# JQuery Link Generator Complication

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, anchor, generator

I wanna learn how to make a generator. From a link, to an image and build upon it. To start with the easiest thing I can think of is generating a simple link.

If below can generate a premade link, then you should be able to set variables for input textbox's where the url and text would me that makeup the link.

```
$('input[name=confirm]').click(function(){
    $('#genarea').append('<a href="http://google.com/">Google</a>');
});
```

So I gave the following a try...

```
$("input[name='confirm']").click(function() {
    var asrc = $("input[name='url']").attr("value");
    var txt = $("input[name='txt']").attr("value");
    $(".genarea").append('<a href="' + (asrc) + '">' + (txt) + '</a>');
});
```

I don't like asking questions as I like to learn myself, but this simple task is a major annoyance. Any help would be greatly appreciated. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/gPsqd/

Comment: Why not .val() instead of attr and why class genarea instead of I'd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the good function. If you wanna get the value of an input, do this :

```
$("input[name='txt']").val();
```

Here the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/gPsqd/1/

Comment: Belive it, it happen to everyone!